# Keep a different version of a file locally in PHPStorm

Tags: php, ftp, phpstorm

I work directly with a development server where I have automatic upload turned on but sometimes I also want to run my PHP project locally on my computer. This usually involves changing a few settings in my database or constants file to match that of my local host rather than the dev server. Project is uploaded via FTP.

I want to have one file locally with my local database settings and one file remotely with my dev server settings. I believe this may also be relevant to other files.

I could exclude the file to prevent uploading but I find this solution to only be half way decent if I want to edit or make changes to my constants file.

Is there a better way to handle this to have a local and a remote version of the same file that exists in the same PHPStorm project?

Comment: use [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) and [push-to-deploy](http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git).  One option certainly.   Thats if you have that much control of the project that is.

Comment: Options:

1) you can create a function to identify what host you are running on and require the corresponding constants for that configuration.
2) make your local and remote environments (database etc) identical.
3) split only the variable constants out to their own file for each environment so that the changes are minimal.

Comment: 1) Define separately (in separate file that will be different on each host) or somehow detect automatically on what host you are now 2) Based on that define certain constants with correct for this host values. Ideally it would be not using constants at all but storing config data in arrays -- this way you can have some general config and then override part of it with data from host-specific settings (MUCH easier than dealing with constants).

Comment: Good ideas, all these could work but they sort of get me half way there. Having identical databases would get me halfway there but only if the host can be localhost. Using a function would work but it might reveal information about my computer to others working on the same dev server. Two seperate files would work but still requires me to modify the same file every time.

Comment: the most optional solution would be that I have a file called config.php with a host, pass, user etc. which PHPStorm could handle for me so that it would keep a local and remote version under the same filename that could be edited seperately..